# blazor web server - change html attribute dynamic

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

hello i build blazor web server app
i use bootstrap

and when i set the data-bs-theme on the html tag to dark or light the all site theme change

i create a ThemeService that read and save thme name value on the local storage and serve for me 2 props of
CurrentTheme
ThemeChanged

```
public class ThemeService
{
   private string _currentTheme = "light"; // default theme

   public string CurrentTheme 
   { 
      get => _currentTheme; 
      set
       {
          if (_currentTheme != value)
          {
             _currentTheme = value;
             ThemeChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
          }
       }
   } 

   public event EventHandler ThemeChanged;

 }
```

all work good but
i dont know how to rerender the root (App.razor) componenet
agin to change the data-bs-theme attribute

App.razor Component

```
@inject ThemeService ThemeService
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="he" data-bs-theme="@ThemeService.CurrentTheme">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<base href="/" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="BNWebClient.styles.css" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
<HeadOutlet @rendermode="GlobalRenderSettings.GlobalRenderMode" />
</head>

<body>
    <ThemeLoader @rendermode="GlobalRenderSettings.GlobalRenderMode" />
    <Routes />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.changeTheme = (theme) => {
          document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-bs-theme",theme)
      }
    </script>
  </body>

</html>

@code{
    [Inject] IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }
    override protected async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            ThemeService.ThemeChanged +=  async (s,e) => {
              await InvokeAsync( async ()=>{
                await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("changeTheme", 
                ThemeService.CurrentTheme);
              });
           };
        }
      }
    }
```

ThemeLoader Componenet

```
<HeadContent>
@if (!ThemeService.CurrentTheme.Equals("light") && !ThemeService.CurrentTheme.Equals("dark"))
{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
}
else
{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap-bnext-rtl.min.css" />
}
</HeadContent>

<button @onclick="Toggle">Toggle</button>

@code {
  [Inject] IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }
  [Inject] ThemeService ThemeService { get; set; }

  protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
  {
      if(firstRender)
      {
      }
      base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
  }

  void Toggle(){
    if(ThemeService.CurrentTheme.Equals("light"))
    {
        ThemeService.CurrentTheme = "dark";
    }
    else
    {
        ThemeService.CurrentTheme = "light";
    }
  }

  private async Task HandleThemeChange(string theme)
  {
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("changeTheme", theme);
  }
}
```